Apache Hadoop 2.10/3.4.0 - compatibility component's versions
Am Planning to setup apache hadoop cluster (2.10/3.4.x) version.
Searched Apache documents but did not get supported components versions
Main components required: Hive , Hbase, spark, zookeeper, nifi.
Are there any version Metrix version...?
Thanks,
kant
I have gone through few apache website getting sourece file (tar) but version metrix did not get version computability.

Hbase has a matrix. https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop

You need to go and check the individual hadoop versions supported for Hive, Hbase or any other downstream versions by checking their release docs or check the pom of those projects to find out which version of Hadoop they are using.
If you don't want to get into those, can explore Apache BigTop which can help get you set up the entire Hadoop ecosystem
